# laravel pdf package that can load views and support arabic

Tags: pdf, laravel-4, view, tcpdf, dompdf

I'm looking for a laravel 4 package that can do both, loading views and supporting arabic (and non-latin) fonts. 
I've tried domPDF and TCPDF but the first doesn't support Arabic while the second can't load views

Comment: dompdf *should* support Arabic characters with an appropriate font, but support is far from perfect yet. wkhtmltopdf and PhantomJS, as headless versions of webkit (i.e. Safari) provide much better rendering across the board.

Answer (score 1):

Try "WKHTMLTOPDF" i use it with ZF2 and have no problems at all. Just google for sure there are packages.

Comment: how can I load views with it, if you notice the setup here it only loads html but not view 
https://github.com/NitMedia/wkhtml2pdf

Comment: @SamJoni there are 2 possible ways. 1. Buffer the view over and send it via piping to wkhtml 2. save the view as html temp.

Comment: @SamJoni i just had a look in the code from the plugin and it has a 'setHtml()' function so just get the view as a string and try this function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the package from Barry? (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) This package has build-in support for views, accessing the storage folder for fonts as well as streaming or downloading the PDF to the user in a

As for the Arabic support. Try the UTF-8 support in DOMPDF. In the example they load (what seems) Chinese characters. I think Arabic wil work as wel. (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo#create-a-compatible-html-document)

Comment: Not working with arabuc