# dompdf package does not support arabic character

Tags: php, laravel, unicode

I am using the `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` package and I want to create a printable page. Here is my code:

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'Arial']);
    $pdf->loadHTML('
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
         <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body style="font-family: Arial">
          <div class="row">
            <p>سلام</p>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
    ');
    return $pdf->stream();
```

But it does not support Arabic characters, instead displaying question marks like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel pdf package that can load views and support arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265020/laravel-pdf-package-that-can-load-views-and-support-arabic)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with any laravel PDF packages.
I just found a package that solved my problem.
[niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf) package did it. It's easy to use and supports RTL languages such as Arabic and Persian.
example:

```
use niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf\Facades\Pdf;

$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.invoice-view', [
    'var1' => $var1,
    'var2' => $var2
], [], [
    'title' => 'Certificate',
    'format' => 'A4-P',
    'orientation' => 'P'
]);

return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
```

you can add this package to your laravel project using this command:

`composer require niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf`

Documentations [HERE](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf).

Comment: Working package for Arabic

Answer (score 0):

Tip: UTF-8 support
In your templates, set the UTF-8 Metatag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```